# How can I add additional data to ASP.NET Authentication Ticket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want add a Json object to the response ticket as property which I get from the authentication token. I tried to add it in AuthenticationProperties but I get the property as string not as a Json Object.

I want to do something like:

```
{
  "access_token": "T_4ZEoW5-ivHRCrZOUq20u4vaChTbg2QYOwwOEcn_vu_lKxePPv-7Hed3HulsLRiVn6IyCAdcsXP4Fb20ZVkVEpWxwvlCf0AxIwMN5jlf3SzvTJM2FGSpT1nWF98GS7mtYuJhpciEnizIw-Cx-QtWgATfq6IlUGAOv9fk8mJJ",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1799,
  "refresh_token": "69c2087223804",
  "as:client_id": "Angular App",
  "userName": "testuser",
  "id": "ca7337cb-42c2-49ea-c9ee-d8d6704583f5",
  ".issued": "Thu, 11 May 2017 08:45:47 GMT",
  ".expires": "Thu, 11 May 2020 09:15:47 GMT",
 "this --> Student": {"name" : "MyName", "surname" : "MySurname"}
}
```

How can I get the property as an object and not as string?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to deserialize your json string into an object, check out this link: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-Csharp.aspx

Comment: y serialize the object, but i get this:  "Student": "{\"name\" : \"MyName\", \"surname\" : \"MySurname\"}"